# Let $V=\mathbb{R^3}, S=\{(x,y,z)|z=x+y\}$

Tags: vector-spaces

Let $V=\mathbb{R^3}, S=\{(x,y,z)|z=x+y\}$

(a) Is closed under addition

(b) Is closed under scalar multiplication.

(c) Is a subspace of V

according to the subspace if (a) and (b) then (c) true

closed under addition => let a,b $\in S$=>a+b$\in  S$

then a+b=$(x_1+x_2+y_1+y_2-(z_1+z_2))$ is in S

Comment: So far so good.  What is next?

Comment: @DougM... Mi have dought that is a+b is in S

Comment: @DougM...the is it scalar multiplcation

Comment: Important: Even after proving (a) and (b), you need to check that $V$ contains $0$ (or equivalently, that it's nonempty) to conclude that it is a subspace.

Answer (score 1):

Let $a = (x_1,y_1,z_1)$ and $b=(x_2,y_2,z_2)$
with $a,b\in S$

$x_1 + y_1 = z_1\\
x_1+y_1-z_1 = 0$

Similarly, $x_2+y_2-z_2 = 0$

Closure under addition:

$a,b \in S \implies a+b\in S\\ x_1+x_2 + y_1+y_2 = z_1+z_2\\
(x_1+y_1-z_1) + (x_2+y_2-z_2) = 0$

Which is true

Closure under scalar multiplication:

$a \in S \implies ca\in S\\ cx_1 + cy_1 = cz_1\\
c(x_1 + y_1 - z_1) = 0$

Also true.

Answer (score 0):

Note, $S=\{(x,y,x+y): (x,y)\in\Bbb R^2\}$

Closure under addition:   is $\big((x_1, y_1, x_1+y_1)+(x_2, y_2, x_2+y_2)\big)~\in~ S$, for all real $x_1,y_1,x_2,y_2$?

Closure under scalar multiplication:   is $a(x, y, x+y) ~\in~ S$, for all real $a,x,y$ ?

Subspace:   does the above hold, and also does $S$ contain $(0,0,0)$

Answer (score 0):

A useful approach is to see if you can cast the set in question into the
form of a null space.

In this case, if you let $f((x,y,z)) = x+y-z$, we see that $V = \ker f$,
hence it is a subspace.